# Jquery could post number with comma but couldn't post with dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

i post 2 datas to my controler and one of them is float. But when i enter value "1.5", my   controller did'nt triger. if i entered 1,5  it was trigered. i didn't understand why?

Here is my code

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 8px;width:100%">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lot" placeholder="Lot">
    @*<input class="input-group-addon" value=".00 TL">*@
</div>
<div class="mgmt10">
    <select name="parity" class="form-control wfl parity" style="margin-right:10px; width:251px;">
        <option value="AUDCAD" selected>AUDCAD</option>
        <option value="AUDCHF">AUDCHF</option>
        <option value="AUDJPY">AUDJPY</option>
        <option value="AUDNZD">AUDNZD</option>
        <option value="AUDUSD">AUDUSD</option>
        <option value="CADJPY">CADJPY</option>
        <option value="CHFJPY">CHFJPY</option>
        <option value="EURAUD">EURAUD</option>
        <option value="EURCAD">EURCAD</option>
        <option value="EURCHF">EURCHF</option>
        <option value="EURGBP">EURGBP</option>
        <option value="EURJPY">EURJPY</option>
        <option value="EURNZD">EURNZD</option>
        <option value="EURTRY">EURTRY</option>
        <option value="EURUSD">EURUSD</option>
        <option value="GAUTRY">GAUTRY</option>
        <option value="GBPAUD">GBPAUD</option>
        <option value="GBPCAD">GBPCAD</option>
        <option value="GBPCHF">GBPCHF</option>
        <option value="GBPJPY">GBPJPY</option>
        <option value="GBPTRY">GBPTRY</option>
        <option value="GBPUSD">GBPUSD</option>
        <option value="NZDUSD">NZDUSD</option>
        <option value="SPTTRY">SPTTRY</option>
        <option value="TRYJPY">TRYJPY</option>
        <option value="USDCAD">USDCAD</option>
        <option value="USDCHF">USDCHF</option>
        <option value="USDJPY">USDJPY</option>
        <option value="USDRUB">USDRUB</option>
        <option value="USDTRY">USDTRY</option>
        <option value="XAGUSD">XAGUSD</option>
        <option value="XAUTRY">XAUTRY</option>
        <option value="XAUUSD">XAUUSD</option>
        <option value="SP500H5">SP500</option>
        <option value="DJ30H5">DJ30</option>
        <option value="NAS100H5">NAS100</option>
        <option value="DE30H5">DE30</option>

        <option value="UKOILG5">BRENT OIL</option>
        <option value="USOILG5">WTI OIL</option>
        <option value="ZCH5">MISIR</option>
        <option value="NGG5">DOĞAL GAZ</option>
        <option value="ZSH5">SOYA</option>
        <option value="ZWH5">BUĞDAY</option>
    </select>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<span class="btn mt14 fnt div-calculate" style="width:100%;" onclick="MarginCalculator()">Çevir</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control mgmt10" id="div-hesap" placeholder="Sonuç" style="margin-bottom:1px;" readonly>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MarginCalculator() {

        var data = {
            frmLot: $(".input-lot").val(),
            frmParity: $(".parity").val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/tr/Tools/MarginCalculator",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                isProcessing = true;
                $("#div-hesap").val("Lütfen bekleyiniz.");
            },
            success: function (response) {

                $("#div-hesap").val(Math.round(response) + " $  teminat gerekmektedir.");

            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Use with `data: JSON.stringify(data),`

Comment: Probably is localization, some countries use , as a decimal point

Answer (score 0):

i solved like 
`var x = $(".input-lot").val();
            var res = x.replace(/\./g, ",");`
but i still wonder why it didn't